# Nested for loop for a triangle

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested

I'm a beginner in java & I really need this answer.
I have been trying to create a triangle in this sequence:

```
1
21
321
4321
54321
```

Even though my syntax is correct, I have been going through logical errors with non-terminating loops.

This is the program which I'm trying to fix:

```
for(i=1;i>=1;i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<=i;j=j-1)
        {
            System.out.print(j);        
        }
        System.out.println(); 
    }
```

Help would really be appreciated for this.

Answer (score 2):

You get non-terminating loop because of this

```
for(i=1;i>=1;i++)
```

The code means, you want to loop the body if `i` greater or equal than 1 (`i>=1`), and this `i` value are always incremented by `1` (`i++`) for each loop, so it always have value greater than `1` and this condition is always correct for the loop code. So you must correct the loop statement.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I fully understood your problem but 
the following code created a nice triangle for me.

```
int i,j;
for(i = 1; i>= 1 && i < 10; i++)
{
    for(j = i; j <= i && j > 0; j = j - 1)
    {
        System.out.print(j);        
    }
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

Comment: @Mateusz what **additional** would you achieve from that?

Comment: @Mateusz Thats largly a matter of style

Comment: @Mateusz As it stands it achieves that, a println() on an active line will just end the active line and move onto the next. It won't put in an extra blank line (unless there was a println() previously that "started" a new active line)

Answer (score 1):

`for(i=1;i>=1;i++)` is not correct in this since increment on 1 will always result in number greater than 1 so the loop will end only after `i = (2^31 -1)` iterations. So for given output your loop should look like this:

```
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j>=1;j--)
        {
            System.out.print(j);        
        }
        System.out.println(); 
    }
```

Comment: *"`for(i=1;i>=1;i++)` is non ending loop*" Well, assuming `i` is an `int`, it's a ***really really long*** loop, but it'll end eventually once `i` rolls over. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Running through the loop

```
for(j=i;j<=i;j=j-1) (assume i is 2 for the example)
```

j=2, is 2<=2, yes:run loop 
j=j-1 (j=2-1=1)

j=1, is 1<=2, yes:run loop
j=j-1 (j=1-1=0)

j=0, is 0<=2, yes:run loop
j=j-1 (j=0-1=-1)

j=-1, is -1<=2, yes:run loop 
j=j-1 (j=-1-1=-2)

etc

j is getting smaller and smaller so it will always be less than 2.

i has exactly the reverse problem, its always getting bigger so it will always be greater than 1.

Comment: p.s. if you're using an IDE (like eclipse or netbeans) try running through programs like this in the debugger to watch it happening

Comment: @user2369194 Thats good to hear, thanks for coming back to update us! Consider accepting (the tick mark) whichever answer helped you the most

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    for(int x=1;x<=5;x++)
    {
        for(int j=x;j>=1;j--) 
        {
            System.out.print(j);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what your code is doing for the benefit of other readers.

Comment: @jens I thought it's just the pattern we have to print That's why I wrote and pasted the code... I will see from next time that I could explain... anyways thanks...